# What is the proper way to do "Checkout with Rebase" and then push the merged files in Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, rebase

In Git, I have two branches: master and myFeatureBranch (which I created via IDEA's new branch while I was on master). In the time since I created myFeatureBranch, other team members have committed several changes to master. I would like to bring in those changes, and I am aware that I will have merge conflicts.

My general idea of how to deal with this is:

- I get all of the commits from master and apply them to my branch
- I deal with any merge conflicts
- I push all of these changes, including the merged files, to the remote branch
- There are no duplicate commits on my remote branch

Intellij IDEA 2016 [added some new features](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/01/intellij-idea-16-eap-improves-editor-and-vcs-integration/) including Checkout with Rebase. From their announcement:

> The *Checkout with Rebase* action is useful if you don’t want to waste your time on extra files synchronization and compilation when you do two operations: Checkout and then Rebase.

Sounds like what I'm wanting. I am already on master, so I click on the branch selector at the bottom right of my IDEA window. I navigate to my local branches and choose "Checkout with Rebase".

[image: Intellij IDEA Checkout with Rebase]

After doing this, I am told about my merge conflicts. I choose the "Merge" button and resolve them manually.

[image: Intellij IDEA Merge Conflict]

After I do that, I get a confirmation that my rebase was successful:

[image: Intellij IDEA Rebase Successful]

And there are no pending changes:

[image: Intellij IDEA No Pending Changes]

Everything looks like it worked. Now I want to push everything, including my merged classes, to my remote branch. So I go to the menu bar and choose VCS -> Git -> Push. But when I do that, I get an error saying that my push was rejected and that I should merge:

[image: Push of current branch <code>myFeatureBranch</code> was rejected. Remote changes need to be merged before pushing. In this case **merge is highly recommended**, because there are non-pushed merge commits. Rebasing them can lead to problems.]

I decided to follow the advice and choose "Merge". However, this brought me right back to the merge conflict.

[image: Intellij IDEA Merge Conflict]

If I go through with this and then try pushing it again, it is successful, but I wind up with two copies of the merge.

What am I doing incorrectly with this "Checkout with Rebase" and then pushing my merged files?

<sub>Also, **I don't want to do this from the Terminal**. That may be easier for some developers, but I would like to learn how to do it entirely through the IDEA GUI (we have QA and other users who are not as technical as our developers and they have expressed a desire to not have to use the command line, and I'd like to know the best way for them).</sub>

Comment: What do you get, if you `git stash` your changes `git reset --hard` your `myFeatureBranch` and try to do that again?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz At what point in the process do you want me to try that? And is this something I'd have to do from the command line? Like I said at the end, I'd like to learn how to do this whole process from the Intellij IDEA GUI, but if command line stuff helps diagnose issues as we figure out what to do, that's fine.

Comment: At the starting point, where you were before the problem occured. But anyway it takes use of command line and you don't want it, because some people are "non-technical" ;>

Comment: Running `git stash` gives `No local changes to save`. Running `git reset --hard` gives `HEAD is now at 3befef2 <the latest commit message> 'origin/myFeatureBranch' into myFeatureBranch` (which is what I expect to see, as I was already up to date). Nothing changes as I repeat this process. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you've got the same problem if you checkout first your feature branch, then rebase it on the master and want to push to remote.

By rebasing your feature branch, you have modified the commit history, either by use "Checkout with Rebase" or doing this manually.
So you can't simply push the new commit tree to remote branch, you've got to push a new commit tree to remote.

In my case, as i usually work alone on feature branch, when i rebase it on master, I use "Force push" option when i want to push my commits on remote branch.

[Force push option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P0VT.jpg)

In that case, git doesn't try to add new commit (calc by diff) on the top of the remote commit tree but erase the entire tree of the remote branch and replace it with the commits of your local feature branch.
Be very careful **if other people work with the remote feature branch**, **don't use this option** ! they'll be in big trouble if they want to push after your forced push because git can't compare their commit history and the new history you've just publish and they can't push their commits (they can't).

There certainly a better way to do this when more than one developper work on feature branch but I don't know it.

Hope than it can help

Answer (score 1):

I also have met such problem when I did rebase. A lot of conflicts resolved and there's problem in the end. Of course, merge isn't good solution from my point, because result won't look so great.

Before rebasing, rename your origin branch which you going to rebase, and then after rebase use your old origin branch name. Or simply after rebasing push changes to new origin branch.

Main point to push to different branch, not to the same. That's help me to resolve this problem.

For example,

```
feature        - - - - 
             /
dev   - - - . - - - - - - . - -
```

Will become to:

```
update-feature               - - - - 
                           /
dev   - - - . - - - - - - . - - - - -
```

And it will be done without any problems.

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a force push because you are rewriting history of your feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can checkout a new branch from master and merge your feature branch into the branch you just created, that way you get your feature branch work included without checking out the feature branch, which could trigger massive unnecessary file changes.